# How do citizens gain EXP?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-2-revenant-kingdom

My citizens have an EXP bar, and some of then are ranked like, Beginner, Veteran...etc.

The EXP bar is increasing on some of my citizens, but I'm not sure what is causing it. Do I just leave my game on or is it system clock based? Is there anything I can do to increase the rate?

Comment: They have to be assigned to a building to earn experience. They don't even have to do anything to earn experience, although I think completing research tasks *does* give more experience, but it is difficult for me to confirm that theory

Answer (score -1):

If you're on the ps4, go to the person while on your managing kingdom mode and hit options button on controller.